# Should you code in case the threads die or freeze?

Tags: c#

I have an app that starts 10 threads.
Each thread does it's work and waits (using the producer consumer model).
So when more work comes along, one of the threads is unblocked and it does the work.

A colleague at work insists I should write some code that monitors the threads "just in case" they freeze/do not respond or die.

So far in my testing, they work fine and close down correctly.

My question is "should I put code in to do this"? If so, "how do I monitor a thread and check it's status"?

Thanks.
JD

Comment: On what thread are you planning on doing the monitoring?  What happens if it "freezes and dies"?

Comment: Each thread is given a job to do which corresponds to a record in the database. As the thread does work it updates the record. If the thread freezes or dies, then if about 10 minutes have elapsed since the last update, another thread clears the record and makes it available for another thread to do work with.

As for your question, I was thinking about launching a new thread from the main thread and that would do the monitoring (but at this stage nothing has been decided)?

My other problem is, if the thread does freeze, I will need to start a new thread. How would I do that?

Comment: You might want to rethink your design....One thread per DB record????!!?!?!?

Comment: @JD, I think what @Eric Lippert was trying to say, was that what happens if your thread that is monitoring the other threads dies, i.e. "Who watches the Watchmen?". You end up in a Catch-22 because you can't trust any thread if you don't trust them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the situation. First of all, you should focus on correctness so that it doesn't freeze or die but if you need more reliability, you should first think about how you can gracefully recover from such a situation. You should think about why it might freeze or die and if it did, now what you can do. If you can't do anything good that reliably recovers from such a situation, you shouldn't even try. If can do it without making the situation worse, then you can go and try doing so.

Obviously, if you made such a choice, you have to be careful not to mess things up and introduce some bugs that actually make the bad stuff happen yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally no, your threads should be able to finish properly. Monitoring them is not worth the complexity and processing time. If you do it correctly you won't need monitoring.

Comment: Thanks. So far, everything seems to work fine and there are no issues with threads dying or freezing. They close down correctly when I close the application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're coding against the .NET framework 2 or above, an unhandled exception in a worker thread will kill the entire app.

Unless you're absolutely sure your thread code won't throw an exception (or reserve memory, or grab a handle, or call framework code you didn't write...) the first thing you'll want to write in your thread entry method is a try/catch.

Comment: There is a try/catch that writes to a log file (using enterprise logging). So on that front, it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your threads spend a lot of time waiting for work, you could consider refactoring your app to use the `System.Threading.ThreadPool` class.  Doing that would offload much of your thread management to the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Threads don't just hang or die unless there is a bug in the user code. The chances of the OS/Framework screwing up is so negligible that it's, for practical purposes, impossible. It's like worry about the hard disk not writing a file even though File.WriteAllBytes() succeeds. It just doesn't happen.

That said, [wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196492/should-you-code-in-case-the-threads-die-or-freeze/1196568#1196568) brings up a good point that an unhandled exception in a worker thread populates up as an unhandled exception through the entire AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is use "ThreadPool" and call ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and .Net manages the ThreadPool very efficiently.

You can set maximum number of threads to allocate and you dont need to do any wait operation etc. You can also get WaitHandle to wait upon completion. And you dont need to manage the blocking/unblocking of threads.

Answer (score -1):

You should always code for the chance that the thread may hang or die, even if all you do is forcibly restart the thread.

Comment: Always! And include some `Debug.Assert(true != false)` statements while you're at it :P

Comment: I agree with Thorarin. See my answer.